# How to execute firebase cloud function one minute after an event occurred?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am using Firebase realtime database for my Android app. I want to execute a firebase function one minute after a database write occurred(not every after 1 minute like Cron job). Is it possible? If possible how can I do that?

Comment: Firebase doesn't support this but you can thing of a work around may be.

Comment: The function is called when it triggers but you can set the setTimeout() function to delay your execution of code.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Functions does not offer delayed invocations, but you can integrate with [Cloud Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/) to arrange for a callback to another function after some delay.

Comment: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a

Answer (score 0):

this is a work around, if you want to be delayed for quite amount of time consider pay attention to the cloud functions timeout option increase it if needed the default timeout is after 60s of the functions first begin executed

```
export const {Your function Name} = functions
  .runWith({ timeoutSeconds: 120 }) // set the timeout in second, (the type is number)
  .https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {}
```

you could wrap everything in you want to be delayed inside the functions in a

`setTimeout(() => {  // your code inside the functions you want it to be delayed }, delay time in seconds)` function

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would to calculate the time in one minute and add this to a database collection.

Then have cloud scheduler trigger a query for all items in that minute and process those items with you functions and delete or update the item in the database.

You could also use this collection to make sure your process completed by updating this table. If the item didn't get updated as completed, you could have another scheduler query to rerun the process.